# Are there any JavaScript methods that can replicate the Oracle's ADD_MONTH() functionality

Tags: javascript, oracle, date

1) Oracle's example of ADD_MONTHS(date, 1):

`SELECT ADD_MONTHS('30-Nov-15', 3) FROM dual;`

> February, 29 2016 00:00:00

2) JavaScript:

```
var date= new Date("Mon Nov 30 2015 00:00:00"); 
date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 3);
```

> Tue Mar 01 2016 00:00:00

Are there any JavaScript methods that can replicate the Oracle's ADD_MONTH() functionality ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to implement the same logik as in Oracle function - i.e. for "shorter" month you do not overflow in the next month, I guess you will need to do it yourself:

Pseudocode:

```
 myDay = date.getDate(); // save the date
 date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 3);  // add months
 myNewDay = date.getDate();
 while  (myDay !=  myNewDay & myNewDay <= 3) {
    myNewDay = myNewDay -1 // go back one day
    date.setDate(myNewDay); // restore the
 }
```

So if you end with the same day of the month after adding months you are ready.
If you get a different day of month, it will be 1,2 or 3 (the difference in month length);
go back day by day until you reach the end of the month.

This is my knowledge of the Oracle algorithm. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

```
date.getMonth()
```

returns the previous months date instead of this months date. So to add to the correct date just do

```
date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 2);
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "returns the previous months date instead of this months date". `getMonth` returns the value of the month corresponding to `date` as a number between 0 (representing January) and 11 (representing December). Thus, if you pass a date constructed with "20-Oct-2015" to `getMonth` it will return 9, where 9 represents October. [Docs here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z284z68x(v=vs.94).aspx). Best of luck.